# Does anyone know the female of "Músico"?

Tags: substantivos, gênero

I found out this tricky question in my Facebook. What's the female of "músico". Is it right to say something like "Joana é uma música" since the word (also) describes the art itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The female of "Músico" is "Música.

Reference -> [Qual é o feminino de músico?](https://ensina.rtp.pt/artigo/qual-e-o-feminino-de-musico/)

Comment: Another reference: [feminino de músico {Flexão nominal}](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/492).

Comment: @Schilive, o que tu propuseste não é uma edição; é uma resposta nova! As edições de respostas de outros devem ser correções e pequenas alterações que mantenham o espírito original. Mas tu podes apresentá-la como resposta tua (embora eu ache que é usar artilharia pesada para matar uma mosca).

Comment: @Jacinto, concordo. Mas acho matar uma mosca com uma bazuca mais divertido do que com um chinelo. Vou colocar a minha resposta, então. Obrigado.

Comment: Confesso que que pode causar um pouco de confusão... "O que ela faz?", "Ela é música", "Ela é o que??", "Música... musicista, etc."

Comment: Pela definição, musicista é alguém que é um apreciador ou amador de música. Definição parece-me diferente.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Maf, the female of músico is música, the same word for the art itself.

Answer (score 1):

A forma correta do feminino da palavra músico é a música.

Answer (score 1):

### English

Most Portuguese nouns have one gender (masculine or feminine) and only change according to number (singular and plural), but some nouns change according to gender and number. There are other noun inflexions, but it would not be efficient to talk about them here. Nouns which show workers or doers, like *músico*, usually change according to gender and number. The following table shows the inflexions of grammatical gender and number of the noun *músico*:

```
          Masculine  Feminine
Singular:  Músico     Música
Plural:    Músicos    Músicas
```

There is usually confusion because the female inflexion “música(s)” of the noun “músico”, which means musician, is equal to the noun “música”, which means song. So “música(s)” can be either female musician or song.

### Português

Em português, a maioria dos substantivos tem um gênero (feminino ou masculino) e se flexionam em número (singular e plural), mas alguns substantivos se flexionam em gênero e número. Há outras desinências de substantivo, mas não seria eficiente falar delas aqui. Substantivos que mostram agentes ou profissionais, como *músico*, geralmente se flexionam em gênero e número. A tabela a seguir mostra as desinências de gênero gramatical e número do substantivo *músico*:

```
          Masculino  Feminino
Singular:  Músico     Música
Plural:    Músicos    Músicas
```

Geralmente, as pessoas (eu incluso) se confundem porque a desinência feminina “música(s)” do substantivo “músico”, que é quem faz música, é igual ao substantivo “música”, composição.

---

Referências/*references*:

[Feminino de músico](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/492);
[Dicionário Houaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#1).

Answer (score 0):

In Brazil, we can use "musicista" as the female for músico. Actually, according to the dictionary that's for both male and female, but "musicista" for female musician sounds much better in Portuguese.

Comment: Hi Lucio, welcome to Portuguese SE! In this case I disagree: to my ears "musicista" sounds quite gender neutral, so much as, say, "artista". Besides, I think it's more often used to mean someone who studies or appreciates music than someone who works with music (though this meaning is also correct).